# convert json string to object and bind to html select in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, select

Below is the response returned from my service, i would like to bind this data to HTML selct dropdown. but the response looks like string not array.

```
    "{"Codes":{  "CountryCodes": [    {      "Code": "002",      "Desc": "AFGHANISTAN"    },    {      "Code": "003",      "Desc": "ALBANIA"    },    {      "Code": "004",      "Desc": "ALGERIA"    }  ]}}"
```

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: Include code from your service, why are you returning a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement">
     <option *ngFor="let country of countryCodes.Codes.CountryCodes" [ngValue]="country.Code"> {{country.Desc}}</option>
  </select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KmIyV0LLvkkYTwS5zpcP?p=preview)**

Comment: I am getting this error in assignment.                                                                         Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"Codes"' does not exist in type 'any[]'